# What php function can give me the position in the array of a given key

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array :

```
$transport = array('a'=>'foot', 'b'=>'bike', 'c'=>'car', 'd'=>'plane');
```

What php function can give me the position in the array of a given key ?

ex :

```
some_function( $transport, 'c')
//expected : 2;
```

Comment: what for do you need position? Just curious

Comment: Oiginaly for finding the position of a value in a hey/value url : index.php/admin/users/search/sort/id/order/desc/email/adc/page/10 but i was over complicating things, i thnik i'm good with a simple array search

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Search](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) the [array's keys](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) for your given key:

```
$pos = array_search('c', array_keys($transport));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use array_search. Here's a code snippet from http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php.

```
<?php
$array = array(0 => 'blue', 1 => 'red', 2 => 'green', 3 => 'red');

$key = array_search('green', $array); // $key = 2;
$key = array_search('red', $array);   // $key = 1;
?>
```

Comment: That's not the position it's the key what gets returned